# How to debug "failed to install apk on device" error using flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am new to Android development and flutter both. I am trying to get started with flutter, and have issues executing the default sample on my device.

Below are the relevant steps I have followed:

- Download and unzip flutter. Make sure Android SDK, git and other prerequisites are correctly installed and configured for flutter
- flutter create myapp
- cd myapp
- flutter run -v

Flutter run does not launch the app on my phone, and ends with the error **Failed to install APK**.

Note that I have never been able to run a flutter app in debug mode on my device

I tried a bunch of things and below are the findings

1. Same error if I try from Android Studio using flutter.
2. I am able to run native Android Apps using Android Studio (without flutter)
3. I am able to run a release build of the app on flutter, but not a debug build

How can I get flutter debug builds to run on my device?

Below are some relevant portions of the output

### Dev Platform

```
 • OS: Windows 7 Ultimate Service pack 1 (64 bit)
 • CPU: AMD FX 8320
```

### flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.3 at D:\Android\Flutter_v1.7.8
    • Framework revision b712a172f9 (8 days ago), 2019-07-09 13:14:38 -0700
    • Engine revision 54ad777fd2
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • ANDROID_HOME = D:\Android\Sdk
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: D:\Android\Android-Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at D:\Android\Android-Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 37.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.1)
    • IntelliJ at D:\Program Files\IntelliJ-IDEA-2019.1.3-jbr11
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • ONEPLUS A5000 • 9586e89d • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)
```

### flutter run (end output only, as the full output is too long)

```
[ +159 ms] Installing APK.
[   +6 ms] executing: D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe version
[  +49 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 29.0.1-5644136
           Installed as D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
[   +3 ms] executing: D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server
[  +41 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 9586e89d install -t -r
D:\BackedupFolder\DevProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk
[+1777 ms] Performing Streamed Install

           adb: failed to install D:\BackedupFolder\DevProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:
[   +3 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk... (completed in 1.8s)
[   +2 ms] Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] Performing Streamed Install

           adb: failed to install D:\BackedupFolder\DevProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\myapp\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk:
[   +3 ms] Warning: Failed to install APK.
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on ONEPLUS A5000.
[   +5 ms] "flutter run" took 43,368ms.
[   +1 ms] "flutter run" took 43,368ms.

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:475:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:478:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:383:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#7      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#8      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:375:20)
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:396:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:356:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#20     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:25)
#21     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
#22     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:112:14)
#23     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:242:18)
#24     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#25     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#26     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#27     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#28     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#29     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:60:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#30     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#33     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#34     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#35     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:152:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#36     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:56:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:51:10)
#38     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:62:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#39     main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#40     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#41     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: Could it be a version issue, Sometimes I get that for my native apps as well. I just try uninstalling the app on my device and then installing a fresh build again. That resolves my issue almost every time..

Comment: there are 2 options I can think of, 1) See if app is already there, long press on app icon and it should give you option to uninstall. If its not there - 2) Go to Settings--> Apps and Notifications --> See All apps --> Look for your app --> Uninstall it.

Comment: @kukroid I don't see the app installed on my device at all. Remember, this is the first time I am trying it out

Answer (score 0):

It appears your Connected device is running Android-28 and your  targeted platform is Android-29. Since your device is running a version less than your build the simple fix might be updating the Connected device to Android 28. 
Then double check the developer options on the hardware device are 'on' and settings correct. Specifically check that 'USB debugging' is on, 'Wait for debugger' is on and 'Verify bytecode of debuggalbe apps' is off.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb5b9.png)